# How to check gradient computation via unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to unit-test a custom layer. Writing the feed-forward test was pretty straight forward, but I have no idea how to implement the test for gradients.

I found out there is a function in the tensorflow test package called `compute_gradient` but I can't find any resource on how to use it. The documentation basically says it computes the gradients (jacobian matrix) which is what I want, but when I try to use it, I get `EagerTensor is not callable`

This I the code that fails:

```py
class LayerGradientTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def test_gradient(self):
        with self.test_session():
            input_tensor = [...]
            expected_output = [...]
            expected_gradients = [...]
            test_layer = MyLayer()
            output_tensor = test_layer(tf.Variable(input_tensor))
            grad_computed = tf.test.compute_gradient(output_tensor, expected_output)
            self.assertAllEqual(grad_computed, expected_gradients)
```

I would expect the test to either pass or fail at the assertion but I get a
`TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable` from `compute_gradient`

**Edit:**
Of course gradients need a loss function, I'm an idiot... but still the output is of nonsense shape. I now use the following code:

```py
function = tf.losses.mean_squared_error
grad_computed = tf.test.compute_gradient(function, [output_tensor, expected_output])
```

The input's shapes to my layer are (1, 2, 2, 3) and (1, 2, 2, 2) but the gradients are a zip object of 4 12x4 matrices but since I have no parameters in my layer I expected to get the error values at the input. Please correct me if I messed something up again. Just to clarify, my layer is just transforming data and therefore has no gradients on its own but must propagate them backwards correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if eager execution is enabled, if not try below code in import

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```